# Python - Update GUI so it always uses the updated list

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a project where I have multiple "Widgets" in a frame. I pass a list of Widgets onto a class called GUI which displays all these "Widgets". I have a button on my frame which needs to delete one of the widgets from the list. Which it does. But the widget itself does not disappear from the frame.

So to clarify

The GUI class has a list of objects `[Object, Object, Object, Object]`. So It now displays 4 Widget objects. When I press the delete button the new list looks like `[Object, Object, Object]` but the list in the GUI class is still `[Object, Object, Object, Object]`. How can I make it so the GUI always uses the newest version of the list?

The code to clarify

```
import random
from tkinter import *
import datetime

root = Tk()
root.configure(background="white")
root.title("Project 2.1")

Widgets = []


class GUI:
    def __init__(self, widgets, master):

        self.widgets = widgets
        self.master = master
        self.master.geometry("{0}x{1}+0+0".format(master.winfo_screenwidth(), master.winfo_screenheight()))

        for widget in range(len(widgets)):
            widgets[widget].widgetFrame.pack(side=LEFT, pady=20, padx=20, fill=Y)

        if len(widgets) == 0:
            NoInputLabel = Label(master, text="No modules connected, please connect a module", font='Helvetica 16 bold')
            NoInputLabel.pack(side=TOP)

        removeButton = Button(master, text="Remove widget", command=self.removeWidget)
        removeButton.pack()

        print(self.widgets)

    def removeWidget(self):
        self.widgets = self.widgets[:-1]
        print(self.widgets)



class Widget:
    def __init__(self, master, name):
        self.master = master
        self.name = name

        colorArray = ["#e3e0f3", "#eebddd", "#80a3db", "#036fa0"]

        self.widgetFrame = Frame(master, bg="white")
        # widgetFrame.pack(side=LEFT, pady=20, padx=50)

        widgetTop = Frame(self.widgetFrame, bg="white")
        widgetTop.pack(side=TOP)

        widgetCenter = Frame(self.widgetFrame, bg="white")
        widgetCenter.pack(side=TOP)

        widgetBottom = Frame(self.widgetFrame, bg="white")
        widgetBottom.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)

        self.WidgetName = Label(widgetTop, text=name, font='Helvetica 16 bold', bg=random.choice(colorArray))
        self.WidgetName.pack(fill=X)

        self.temperatureSliderLabel = Label(widgetTop, text="Temperature (°C)", bg="white")
        self.temperatureSliderLabel.pack()

        self.temperatureSlider = Scale(widgetTop, orient=HORIZONTAL, length=250, from_=0, to=40, bg="white")
        self.temperatureSlider.pack()

        self.lightSliderLabel = Label(widgetTop, text="Light Intensity (%)", bg="white")
        self.lightSliderLabel.pack()

        self.lightSlider = Scale(widgetTop, orient=HORIZONTAL, length=250, bg="white")
        self.lightSlider.pack()

        self.maxRolloutPositionLabel = Label(widgetTop, text="Rolling distance (cm): ", bg="white")
        self.maxRolloutPositionLabel.pack()

        self.maxRolloutEntry = Entry(widgetTop, bg="white")
        self.maxRolloutEntry.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.submitFormButton = Button(widgetTop, text="Submit", command=self.setSensors, bg="white")
        self.submitFormButton.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.openSunblindButton = Button(widgetCenter, text="Open sunblind", command=self.openSunblind, state=NORMAL,
                                         bg="#28a745", fg="white")
        self.openSunblindButton.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.closeSunblindButton = Button(widgetCenter, text="Close sunblind", command=self.closeSunblind,
                                          state=NORMAL, bg="#dc3545", fg="white")
        self.closeSunblindButton.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.setSunblindStatusButton = Button(widgetCenter, text="Automatic", command=self.setSunblindStatus,
                                              bg="#6c757d", fg="white")
        self.setSunblindStatusButton.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.sunblindFrame = Frame(widgetBottom, bg="white")
        self.sunblindFrame.pack(fill=X)

        self.sunblindStatusLabel = Label(self.sunblindFrame, text="Sunblind status:", bg="white", anchor="w")
        self.sunblindStatusLabel.pack(side=LEFT, pady=5)
        self.sunblindStatus = Label(self.sunblindFrame, text="Manual", bg="white")
        self.sunblindStatus.pack(side=RIGHT, pady=5)

        self.temperatureFrame = Frame(widgetBottom, bg="white")
        self.temperatureFrame.pack(fill=X)

        self.temperatureValueLabel = Label(self.temperatureFrame, text="Temperature: ", justify=LEFT, bg="white",
                                           anchor="w")
        self.temperatureValueLabel.pack(side=LEFT, pady=5)
        self.temperatureValue = Label(self.temperatureFrame, text="", bg="white")
        self.temperatureValue.pack(side=RIGHT, pady=5)

        self.lightSliderFrame = Frame(widgetBottom, bg="white")
        self.lightSliderFrame.pack(fill=X)

        self.lightSliderValueLabel = Label(self.lightSliderFrame, text="Light Intensity: ", justify=LEFT, bg="white",
                                           anchor="w")
        self.lightSliderValueLabel.pack(side=LEFT, pady=5)
        self.lightSliderValue = Label(self.lightSliderFrame, text="", bg="white")
        self.lightSliderValue.pack(side=RIGHT, pady=5)

        self.rolloutFrame = Frame(widgetBottom, bg="white")
        self.rolloutFrame.pack(fill=X)

        self.rolloutLabel = Label(self.rolloutFrame, text="Roll-out position: ", justify=LEFT, bg="white", anchor="w")
        self.rolloutLabel.pack(side=LEFT, pady=5)
        self.rolloutValue = Label(self.rolloutFrame, text="", bg="white")
        self.rolloutValue.pack(side=RIGHT, pady=5)

        self.variable = StringVar(widgetBottom)
        self.variable.set(self.name)
        self.chooseArduino = OptionMenu(widgetBottom, self.variable, "Living Room", "Bedroom", "Study", "Sex Dungeon",
                                        "Bingo club")
        self.chooseArduino.pack()

        self.setNameButton = Button(widgetBottom, text="Set name", command=self.setArduinoName)
        self.setNameButton.pack()

    def setSensors(self):
        print("Set the temperature and light of the sensors")
        self.temperatureValue.config(text=str(self.temperatureSlider.get()) + "°C")
        self.temperature = self.temperatureSlider.get()
        self.lightSliderValue.config(text=str(self.lightSlider.get()))
        self.lightIntensity = self.lightSlider.get()
        self.maxRolloutPositionLabel.config(text="Rolling distance (cm): " + str(self.maxRolloutEntry.get()))

    def setName(self, widgetName):
        self.widgetName = widgetName

    def openSunblind(self):
        print("Set the sunblind to an open state")
        self.rolloutValue.config(text="Rolled out")

    def closeSunblind(self):
        print("Set the sunblind to an closed state")
        self.rolloutValue.config(text="Rolled in")

    def setSunblindStatus(self):
        if self.setSunblindStatusButton.config('text')[-1] == 'Automatic':
            self.openSunblindButton.config(state=DISABLED)
            self.closeSunblindButton.config(state=DISABLED)
            self.setSunblindStatusButton.config(text='Manual')
            print("Sunblind is set to: " + self.setSunblindStatusButton['text'])
            self.sunblindStatus.config(text="Automatic")
        else:
            self.openSunblindButton.config(state=NORMAL)
            self.closeSunblindButton.config(state=NORMAL)
            self.setSunblindStatusButton.config(text='Automatic')
            print("Sunblind is set to: " + self.setSunblindStatusButton['text'])
            self.sunblindStatus.config(text="Manual")


    def setArduinoName(self):
        self.WidgetName.config(text=self.variable.get())


    def getTemperature(self):
        return self.temperature

    def getLightIntensity(self):
        return self.lightIntensity


Arduino1 = Widget(root, "Arduino 1")
Arduino2 = Widget(root, "Arduino 2")
Arduino3 = Widget(root, "Arduino 3")
Arduino4 = Widget(root, "Arduino 4")
Arduino5 = Widget(root, "Arduino 5")
Widgets.append(Arduino1)
Widgets.append(Arduino2)
Widgets.append(Arduino3)
Widgets.append(Arduino4)
Widgets.append(Arduino5)
Visueel = GUI(Widgets, root)

root.mainloop()
```

Image

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like

```
def removeWidget(self):
    widget = self.widgets.pop()
    widget.widgetFrame.pack_forget()
    print(self.widgets)
```

Comment: It worked thanks! Do you also know the way to add a widget and the GUI updates? I used the update method but that does not work